# How to save a Flutter canvas as a bitmap image?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter [canvas](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) , and I'd like to save that canvas as a bitmap image (e.g. PNG, but any common bitmap format will do). What's the best way to get the bits out of a canvas, converted to a bitmap image format?

Comment: it has been [implemented](https://github.com/flutter/engine/commit/b6f466b344108731e26dbdf44a11a3c98d70f696), you can now follow all the Collin's steps.

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320479/flutter-how-would-one-save-a-canvas-custompainter-to-an-image-file/52279202#answer-52279202

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320479/flutter-how-would-one-save-a-canvas-custompainter-to-an-image-file/52279202#answer-52279202 this answer may help

Answer (score 12):

1. Create a [`PictureRecorder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PictureRecorder-class.html).
2. Create a [`Canvas`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) with your `PictureRecorder` and draw stuff.
3. Call [`endRecording()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PictureRecorder/endRecording.html) on the `PictureRecorder` to get a [`Picture`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Picture-class.html).
4. Call [`toImage()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Picture/toImage.html) on the `Picture`.
5. Call [`toByteData()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image/toByteData.html) on the [`Image`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html).