# How to get an image from a canvas drawn with CustomPainter?

Tags: image, canvas, dart, flutter, custom-painting

In my Flutter app I use a [CustomPainter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) to allow a user to draw their signature on the screen. I need to find a way to save this as an image.

[PictureRecorder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/PictureRecorder-class.html) works nicely when you are able to pass the `PictureRecorder` object to the canvas as per [previous StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320479/flutter-how-would-one-save-a-canvas-custompainter-to-an-image-file/52279202#answer-52279202):

```dart
final recorder = new PictureRecorder();
Canvas(recorder).drawSomething;
final picture = recorder.endRecording();
```

However when using `CustomPainter` the canvas is an argument of the `Paint()` function.

```dart
class myPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    drawToCanvas(canvas);

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) {
    return false; 
}
```

So in summary:

How can I produce an image from a CustomPainter?
If the answer is to use a PictureRecorder, how can I pass the recorder to the canvas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to pass the `PictureRecorder` to the canvas in the `CustomPainter` `paint` method. Instead you can call paint directly with a different canvas that has a picture recorder. For Example:

```dart
Future<Image> getImage() async {
final PictureRecorder recorder = PictureRecorder();
myPainter.paint(Canvas(recorder), mySize);
final Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();

return await picture.toImage(width, height);
}
```

Comment: Hi my friend, I have an error trying to implementing your answer. myPainter is a class, so how you manage this?