# How to manipulate an image to add border to it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image-processing, image-manipulation

Which Flutter image manipulation library to use that offers the ability to add a border to the actual image before saving it?

**(Not just printing the border around it on screen)**

I couldn't find any on the internet! Please, include any example in your answer.

Comment: This question might goes under *Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more* you can try customPaint , not sure about the result

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I need any trick or code sample to add a border to the actual image. I found that Paint and similar methods are useful to print something to the screen but not to modify the image.

Comment: [How would one save a Canvas/CustomPainter to an image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50320479/10157127) this may help

Answer (score 0):

You can use image editor package from pub.dev i think you will find the solution.

Comment: I found that it offers drawing capabilities. Not adding a border to an existing image.